# how to set fix background image for windows form c#?

Tags: c#, background-image

I have a windows form application.I set background image for this form and BackgroundImagelayout property is Stretch.When I put a button on the specified place on image and run this app,place moving and commix my design
What should I do? Help me please

Comment: Are you saying that the button is moving around?

Comment: Also, just by using Stretch on the background instead of making a background that fits the form size you want, you'll end up with background elements moving around.

Comment: "place moving and commix my design", this statement makes no sense. Please explain exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

- Define the size of the form
- make the form not resizable
- make the image same size of the form
- fix the background, not stretch
- set the anchor property of objects to top left

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make a layout that can size, you will need to break up your graphical elements into multiple parts, and then use layout controls with parts of the background image that can reposition as the form resizes.

For example, your form can have a tiled pattern, stretched gradient, or whatever you may have. Then, you can have a TableLayoutPanel that contains evenly spaced buttons and fields. The panel can have a background image of its own. The same goes for the other layout containers. You can nest the containers if the design requires it.

Then, you can set the various anchors and docking to keep the design uniform.

Comment: If this is not what you are looking for, be a little more specific, and I can provide more details.